# Infectious Curse vs. Tree of Perdition and Triskaidekaphobia

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This is mainly a question about APNAP order, so my opponent taps their [Tree of Perdition](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTree%20of%20Perdition%5d) at the beginning of their upkeep  in response to [Triskaidekaphobia](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTriskaidekaphobia%5d)'s triggered ability. So my question is as the non-active player can I cause [Infectious Curse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInfectious%20Curse%5d) to activate between the tree and 13 phobia going off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you already know how to figure out the answer. APNAP means active player, then non-active player. The active player's triggers go on the stack first, so they resolve last.

I'm guessing your opponent is the one with the Triskaidekaphobia, since they're playing Tree of Perdition. If that's the case, and your opponent is playing well, then:

- Triskaidekaphobia's triggered ability (controlled by the active player) goes on the stack.
- Infectious Curse's ability (controlled by you, the non-active player) goes on the stack.
- Infectious Curse's ability resolves, you gain 1 life, and your opponent loses 1 life.
- Your opponent activates Tree of Perdition's ability.
- Tree of Perdition's ability resolves, and your life total is now 13.
- Triskaidekaphobia's ability resolves, and you lose.

If *you* control the Triskaidekaphobia, both triggers are yours, and you get to choose what order they go on the stack. But still, however you stack it, your opponent can wait until Triskaidekaphobia's triggered ability is on the top of the stack, activate Tree of Perdition, and you'll lose.

The only way you can save yourself from that is if you have an *activated* ability that you can choose when to activate. Infectious Curse doesn't help here, because it's a triggered ability.

If your opponent is playing badly, sure, they might activate Tree of Perdition before Infectious Curse's ability resolves, and end up with you at 14 instead of 13 when Triskaidekaphobia's ability resolves. But that's not really something you can count on!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, your opponent controls a Triskaidekaphobia, and you control an Infectious Curse enchanting your opponent. At the beginning of your opponent's upkeep, both trigger. As the active player, your opponent would put Triskaidekaphobia's trigger on the stack, then your trigger would go on top. Your opponent can't activate tree in between.

If your opponent activates Tree of Perdition at this point, it will put you at 13 life, then Infectious Curse will bring you up to 14, and you survive. However, if your opponent waits for the Curse trigger to resolve first, they can activate the Tree with their original trigger on the stack, which will cause you to lose.